# Firebase apple-app-site-association how to add webcredentials

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, apple-app-site-associate

I would like to know how we can add `webcredentials` data for autofill to `apple-app-site-association` file which Firebase generates automatically?

I know that setting `appAssociation: NONE` will prevent the automatic generation of this file. However, I do see many benefits in it being generated automatically, so I hope there is a way to add webcredentials to it.